# How to combine / DRY with interfaces

Tags: typescript

This may be a basic question but...

It seems I am duplicating interfaces so how can this avoided, there must be a *DRY'er* way

For example, I have a Users interface:

```
export interface Users {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    username: string,
    email: string,
    address: Address,
    phone: string,
    website: string,
    company: Company
}

export interface Address {
    street: string,
    suite: string,
    city: string,
    zipcode: string,
    geo: Geo
}

export interface Geo {
    lat: string,
    lng: string
}

export interface Company {
    name: string,
    catchPhrase: string,
    bs: string,
}
```

And a User interface,

```
import { Address, Company } from "./Users";

export interface User {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    username: string,
    email: string,
    address: Address,
    phone: string,
    website: string,
    company: Company
}

export interface UserData {
    street?: string,
    zipcode?: string,
    city?: string,
    email?: string,
    phone?: string,
    id?: number
}


export interface UserResult {
    street: string,
    zipcode: string,
    city: string,
    email: string,
    phone: string,
    id: number
}
```

All used for posting or fetching data from the https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users API

Comment: what is the difference between `User` and `Users`?

Comment: Shouldn't you just define `Users` as an array of `User`: `type Users = User[]` ?

Comment: It does seem weird that `Users` and `User` are the same type, but I'll assume it's intentional.  Anyway, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJXB5N) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me).

Comment: If, for some reason, the `Users`/`Address`/`Geo`/`Company` are set in stone, then you could use [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB514w) to define the remaining ones in terms of them.  Let me know (and mention @jcalz) if you want to see that version instead.